# mod_authz_host new statements for Deny directive

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-access, mod-authz-host

I was using the following in my Apache 2.1 installation:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from 203.XXX.YYY
Deny from 10.ABC
Deny from 10.CBA
Deny from 10.BCA
Deny from 10.ACB
```

After updating to 2.4.7; I'm supposed to use the [`mod_authz_host`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html) because of the following

> ### Note
>
> The directives provided by `mod_access_compat` have been deprecated by
>   the new authz refactoring. Please see `mod_authz_host`.

I've read the page linked above, and there is no mention of denying certain IP ranges using the `Require` directive. For now, I've the following in my conf file:

```
Require all granted
```

I tried using the following:

```
Require ip 10.142 denied
```

But `apachectl -t` tells me:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 22 of <path_to_apache2>/conf/myown.conf:
ip address 'denied' appears to be invalid
```

How do I rewrite my former statements in the newer module?

Comment: The [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html) appears to have several examples showing exactly the syntax you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on documentation can you replace this line:

```
Require ip 10.142 denied
```

By this code:

```
Require all granted
Require not ip 10.142
# more Require not lines
```

---

### EDIT

The above needed to be put inside `<RequireAll>` tags:

```
<RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    Require not ip 10.142
</RequireAll>
```

Comment: It still shows an error: `AH00526: Syntax error on line 22 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/myown.conf:
negative Require directive has no effect in <RequireAny> directive`

Comment: If you search for that error message, you find, among other things: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53069

Comment: Read more about Require syntax here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require and see **`Syntax: Require [not] entity-name [entity-name] ...`** part I didn't suggest `RequireAny`